# ScrollWindowEx is not scrolling the window properly. [Windows API]

Tags: python, winapi

I have a window that has a bunch and I want to use a scrollbar when the buttons exceed the height of the window. The problem is that when I use ScrollWindowEx, it kind of moves stuff up. Precisely, the last button's height keeps on increasing and hides the buttons that are supposed to show up . When I hover over the buttons, the new buttons render in the window. I am not sure what is causing that behavior. Someone previously told me to read the remarks from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex), which I did. I am not sure what exactly they were referring to in the paragraph. I am guessing it's the third paragraph in the remarks section that tells to use DeferWindowPos, but I am not sure if am supposed to use that. Please help me, as I have to make it work for a school project :)

In order to run the code, you will also need [user32.py](https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/ff484e75dc9b29e96a7f1e526fcf82f8)

This is main.py

```
from os import listdir
from user32 import *
from button import Button
from pathlib import Path

hInst = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)
buttons = []

BTN_WIDTH = 300
BTN_HEIGHT = 100
LINES = 28

def window_proc(hwnd: HWND, umsg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT:
    si = SCROLLINFO()
    si_pointer = pointer(si)
    match umsg:
        case WindowMessage.CREATE:
            create_list_of_buttons(get_files(), hwnd)
        case WindowMessage.DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0)
            return 0
        
        case WindowMessage.SIZE:
            height = (HIWORD(lparam))
            width = (LOWORD(lparam))

            si.cbSize = sizeof(si)
            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.RANGE | ScrollInfoMessage.PAGE
            si.nMin = 0
            si.nMax = LINES
            si.nPage = height * BTN_HEIGHT;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer, True)

        case WindowMessage.COMMAND:
            if wparam >= 100:
                btn_clicked = ([button for button in buttons if button.hMenu == wparam])
                filename = btn_clicked[0].btn_text
                print(filename)
                rect = RECT()
                rect_p = pointer(rect)
                print(GetClientRect(hwnd, rect_p))
                print(rect.top, rect.bottom, rect.left, rect.right)
        case WindowMessage.VSCROLL:
            si.cbSize = sizeof(si)
            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.ALL
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer)

            yPos = si.nPos
            match LOWORD(wparam).value:
                case ScrollBarCommands.LINEUP:
                    si.nPos -= 1
                case ScrollBarCommands.TOP:
                    si.nPos = si.nMin
                case ScrollBarCommands.BOTTOM:
                    si.nPos = si.nMax
                case ScrollBarCommands.LINEUP:
                    si.nPos -= 1
                case ScrollBarCommands.LINEDOWN:
                    si.nPos += 1
                case ScrollBarCommands.PAGEUP:
                    si.nPos -= si.nPage
                case ScrollBarCommands.PAGEDOWN:
                    si.nPos += si.nPage
                case ScrollBarCommands.THUMBTRACK:
                    print(si.nPos)
                    si.nPos = si.nTrackPos
                    print(si.nPos)

            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.POS
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer, True)
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer)
            if(si.nPos != yPos):
                ScrollWindowEx(hwnd, 0, (yPos - si.nPos), None, None, None, None, 0x0001)
                UpdateWindow(hwnd)

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam)


def create_window(className, windowName):
    wnd_main = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        className,
        windowName,
        WindowStyles.OVERLAPPED
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.SYSMENU
        | WindowStyles.THICKFRAME
        | WindowStyles.MINIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.MAXIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.VSCROLL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        600,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        hInst,
        0,
    )
    if not wnd_main:
        print("Window Creation Falid: ", GetLastError())
        return
    return wnd_main


def get_files():
    folder_path = Path(__file__).parent / "log"
    return [file for file in listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith(".txt")]

def create_list_of_buttons(filenames: list[str], parent_window):
    """
    Makes a list of button that have the file's name as their heading
    """
    x, y = 0, 0
    for button_id, filename in enumerate(filenames, 100):
        button = Button(filename, x, y, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT, parent_window, button_id)
        button.create_button()
        buttons.append(button)
        y += BTN_HEIGHT

    return buttons




def main():
    wclassName = ctypes.c_wchar_p("My")
    wname = ctypes.c_wchar_p("Left")
    wndClass = WNDCLASSEXW()
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)
    wndClass.style = ClassStyles.HREDRAW | ClassStyles.VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WNDPROC(window_proc)
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0
    wndClass.hInstance = hInst
    wndClass.hIcon = 0
    wndClass.hCursor = 0
    wndClass.hBrush = windll.gdi32.GetStockObject(0)
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = 0
    wndClass.lpszClassName = wclassName
    wndClass.hIconSm = 0
    RegisterClassExW(byref(wndClass))
    wnd_main = create_window(wclassName, wname)
    ShowWindow(wnd_main, 5)
    UpdateWindow(wnd_main)

    msg = MSG()
    lpmsg = pointer(msg)
    while (GetMessageW(lpmsg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0:
        TranslateMessage(lpmsg)
        DispatchMessageW(lpmsg)


main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is unclear. *If the SW_SCROLLCHILDREN flag is specified, the system does not properly update the screen if part of a child window is scrolled. The part of the scrolled child window that lies outside the source rectangle is not erased and is not properly redrawn in its new destination. To move child windows that do not lie completely within the rectangle specified by prcScroll, use the DeferWindowPos function."*

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it because I am not even sure if DeferWindowPos will work. I just wanted some confirmation :)

Comment: Also, I am trying to move just one window, shouldn't I use MoveWindow or SetWindowPos? Which one is better for my use-case?

Comment: ScrollWindowEx only scrolls child windows within the area you give it. If any part of them lie outside then they're not redrawn properly, as you've seen. If they lie completely outside the area then they won't be moved at all. Rather than using ScrollWindowEx you should use DeferWindowPos to move all your child windows yourself. If you only have one child window then MoveWindow/SetWindowPos will be fine but for more than one window at once, DeferWindowPos is better.